# How to parse a pdf page and get the all the images in that page?

Tags: ios, image, pdf

I want to parse a pdf page ,which contains some images ! And Ios provide the Quartz 2D to do the job ! But as i went to it's document referece , there are only some basic introduction that teaching how to create PDF Document , view it , and do somme transforming ! Besides , although in the "PDF Document Parsing" reference there is some example code , but i haven't find the code sinppets that meet my demand ！In the "CGPDFDictionaryGetStream" function ,
i can't find the description about the "key" param ! Is somebody else has the same problem , and how to get through it ! Thanks !!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475450/extracting-images-from-a-pdf