# Replace image(s) in PDF in swift. How to get image position in page?

Tags: swift, pdf, cgpdfdocument, ios-pdfkit

I need to replace images in a `PDFDocument` or `CGPDFDocument`.

I found a way to extract images using the old Core Graphics API (i.e. not PDFKit). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458670/how-do-you-extract-images-from-pdf-using-swift).

Now I would like to make a copy of a PDF but by replacing the existing images.
How can I get the width/height & coordinates of the existing images in the source PDF?

PDF are sooo complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are able to extract images, check the image to find out what are their dimensions?

Comment: Actually I need the dimensions inside the PDF itself, not the image dimensions

Comment: vomi, did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I think I'd have to edit the PDF tree manually... I did not go there yet.

Comment: Hey @vomi, did you manage to edit the tree? I am trying to do something similar (remove background from the page) I already modified the stream of the page. But I am unable to save it back. Would be so happy if you figured out how to do so :pray:

Comment: No I did not, unfortunately. PDF specs are a nightmare.